# Docusign : In person signing: Can Host enter the access code before releasing the control to signers?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign - In Person Signing feature. As per it behavior, Host receives
an accesscode in the email.

Host : UserA
Signer: UserB

1. User A clicks on begin signing
2. User A asked to pass the controle to User B
3. At this time, docusign asked the user to enter access code.
   ---Here, the question is access code was sent to User A not User B then why the system is asking the access code after UserA release the control to User B? So, it is like asking userB to enter the accesscode which he has not received.

Is there anyway userA can enter the accesscode before passing the control to UserB?

Please advice?

Comment: Are you creating the envelope through the DocuSign Website or through the API?  In either case, what does "UserA" look like when you add them, do they have an access code configured in their recipient settings?  Solution might be as simple as removing that access code and configuring an access code for the other signer...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the access code is to authenticate that the signer (User B) is who he says he is. The best access code is something that only the system and signer know. Eg, in the US, the last 5 digits of the Social Security number.

The access code is *not required*, someone has configured the signer's field on the document to use an access code.

If you don't want the signer to have an access code, then don't require one.

From your question, it sounds like you don't want any access code.

Having the Host enter the access code negates any authentication value from the access code. So having the Signing Host enter the access code is not a best practice (kinda the opposite, in fact).

You still have the question of how to authenticate the signer. One way is to have the host sign after the signer. And as part of the signing process, the host attests (use a check box or similar), that she has authenticated the signer's identity by checking their driver's license, etc.

Comment: I need access code but my question is if we are asking the signer to enter the access code then Signer should get an email with the access code not the host.

In my case, i am using in person signing feature so Host gets the email with access code which is correct. But rather than asking the host to enter the access code, docusign asks the signer why?

Thanks Showji

Comment: Why do you "need" the access code? Also, your integration can send the access code to the signer via email or use sms. Sending the access code to the signer via the host is weak authentication.

Comment: 1. I need access code to authenticate the host. The only option at present is to send it via email along with the document[Docusign says it is weak in terms of security still this is a only option as i cannot send this access code in a separate email]

Answer (score 0):

I need access code but my question if we are asking the signer to enter the access code then Signer should get an email with the access code.

In my case, i am using in person signing feature so Host gets the email with access code which correct. But rather than asking the host to enter the access code, docusign asks the signer why?

Thanks
Showji

Comment: Next time edit your question rather than giving an answer which is really re-stating your question. As I said in my answer, the idea is that the signer already knows the access code, it should be something already known or the access code should be delivered using something other than email. Sending the access code to the host can be done but is not much of an authentication technique of the signer. The goal is to authenticate the signer. The host doesn't "need" the access code.